# c# Linq order by children

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, children

I have a one (person) to many (pet) relationship and I would like to order by the name attribute of the parent and then order the children by their name attribute

Example of the results I would like:

```
Person: Bill
Pet: dog
Pet: fish

Person: Roger
Pet: cat
Pet: monkey
Pet: horse
```

I have tried the following and it did order by the children:

```
var result3 = SystemContext.Person
.OrderBy(tt => tt.Name)
.ThenBy(tt => tt.Pet.OrderBy(tte => tte.Type).FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

Any ideas would be appriciated

Comment: This will only affect the ordering between Persons with equal Names but different Pets. If you're picking a Person and then checking the order of their Pets, the results will be in the order of the actual Pets collection.

Comment: could you show me build of entities? (Pet and Person).

Comment: I voted this up because it's much better than many other first posts I see, in that you've shown us what you already tried. That said, please be a little more specific on what you're actually looking for. Could we see a few more examples and how they'd be ordered? Please be sure to include every case you're thinking of (for instance people with the same name).

Answer (score 0):

If i get correctly what you wan't, you could do something like this:

```
var result = SystemContext.Person.OrderBy(t=>t.Name)
             .Select(x=>new {Person = x, Pets = x.Pet.OrderBy(p=>p.Type))
```

The result, will be an ordered collection of objects, having two properties- Person and Pets. The pets will be ordered for each Person as well.